# How to Present a UIViewController similar to MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: swift, iphone, user-interface, presentmodalviewcontroller

I try to present a UIViewController similar to the way a MFMailComposeViewController is presented. but I did not find which modalPresentationStyle to use.

[image: MFMailComposeViewController]

Comment: I recommend you this link https://github.com/kbpontius/iOSComposeAnimation

Answer (score 0):

You can display a modal dialog like that using the pageSheet style.  Select the Segue in the storyboard and select "Page Sheet".  This example shows Form Sheet (which is slightly smaller) - but you can select Page Sheet in that same drop down to get the larger modal dialog.

If you are building the controller yourself, here's an example:

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.Storyboard.main, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyControllerIDFromStoryboard")

        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
```

If you're using `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` you can put the attribute on the segue itself in the storyboard.

[image: Form Sheet]